# a static web server demo used gevent in python

Tags: python, gevent

there is some problems with my static web server demo used gevent in python.when my browser visit my web server with http://localhost:8080.It dosen't have any response.If my static web server demo do not use gevent, it works well, it must be some wrong with gevent.

```
#coding=utf-8
from socket import *
from gevent import monkey
import re
import gevent

monkey.patch_all()

def handle_client(client_socket):

    recv_data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    response_header_lines = recv_data.splitlines()
    for line in response_header_lines:
        print(line)

    http_request_line = response_header_lines[0]
    get_file_name = re.match("[^/]+(/[^ ]*)", http_request_line).group(1)
    print("file name is ===>%s"%get_file_name)  #for test

    if get_file_name == "/":
        get_file_name = DOCUMENTS_ROOT + "/index.html"
    else:
        get_file_name = DOCUMENTS_ROOT + get_file_name

    print("file name is ===2>%s"%get_file_name)

    try:
        f = open(get_file_name, "rb")
    except IOError:
        response_header = "HTTP/1.1 404 not found\r\n"
        response_header += "\r\n"
        response_body = "404 not found"
    else:
        response_header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        response_header += "\r\n"
        response_body = f.read()
        f.close()
    finally:
        client_socket.send(response_header.encode("utf-8"))
        client_socket.send(response_body)
        client_socket.close()

def main():

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(("", 8080))
    server_socket.listen(128)
    while True:
        client_socket, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
        #handle_client(client_socket)
        gevent.spawn(handle_client, client_socket)

    server_socket.close()

DOCUMENTS_ROOT = "./html"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should apply monkey patch *before* import any module that will be patched, `socket` in question here:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from socket import *

...
```

[its doc](http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.monkey.html) emphasized:

> Patching should be done as early as possible in the lifecycle of the
>   program. For example, the main module (the one that tests against
>   **main** or is otherwise the first imported) should begin with this code, ideally before any other imports